# Are the siren tones in electronic siren system generated by waveform generator chips or just playing audio files?

Tags: circuit-design, design

The sounds of a Siren tone defined by SAE Standards are basically different ranges and speeds of frequency sweeps played through an amplifier + speaker. Then in a modern electronic siren system for emergency vehicles (the one installed in Police car, ambulance, fire trucks and such), are they using a waveform generator chips (I just assume is MCU tells the chip to generate different waveform of a specific siren tone and play it thru amplifier + speaker whenever a siren tone button is pressed) to generate the tone or just simply playing pre-recorded siren tone? (like playing MP3 files?)

What are the advantages and disadvantages in both ways? (Design difficulty and price-wise)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most early electronic sirens used transistor oscillators. Later ones used logic ICs and Voltage Controlled Oscillators (VCO) to generate the tones. The 'Air Horn' tone in these is done with a pseudo-random noise generator. There are still digital logic and VCO based ones being sold today, such as the popular [Federal Signal PA 300](https://www.fedsig.com/product/pa300-series). You can download a service manual [here](https://elektrotanya.com/federal_pa300_siren_sm.pdf/download.html) to see a schematic of early models, current ones use a very similar circuit.

Some sirens use a microprocessor, but as far as I know almost all of them generate the tones on the fly, not with stored digital audio.

The amplifiers are generally transformer coupled and run pretty much saturated, the output is more a square wave than a sine wave. This allows them be more efficient and output 100 W to 200 W without needing a large heat sink. This could be one reason why they don't bother with stored audio, the sound quality doesn't need to be very high anyway. For the PA and Radio Rebroadcast functions where voice is going to be amplified the bias to the audio PA is switched to a slightly more linear mode to reduce distortion.

Answer (score 1):

This will be different for different sirens. There's no reason to assume all police cars/ambulances of the last 50 years use the same technical system.

Since this is a very easy problem to solve, any modern microcontroller could generate the waveform itself, and feed it directly to a built-in DAC, and thus to an audio amplifier – or it could reasonably "fake" a DAC by using its built-in PWM unit, since you want loud noise, not HiFi-quality. So, in some systems that might be done. In other systems, there might already be a digital audio codec, e.g. for loudspeaker/megaphone purposes, so that the microcontroller just generates a digital audio signal for that to produce. In yet other systems, there might be some recorded audio fed to the audio codec, or the audio codec might have a siren mode, or the audio processing and siren might be done by the car radio. The last one seems especially likely in police cars equipped with radios that can be directly used to make announcements.

So, no reasons to assume it's one or the other way. It's probably all of that, in different cars, and mixtures of all these solutions.

As to advantages/disadvantages: Finances. It's always finances, and legacy reasons. Last generation of cars did it this way? So it's either switching to a new system, with new bugs, and new control interface for the employees, or keeping the old, technically obsolete one. Would be 1€ cheaper to do it one way or the other, because the factory where the last chip was made just burned down? OK, do it the cheaper way…

Answer (score 1):

A modern inexpensive MCU chip such as a STM32F411 has 256K or 512K of flash. If we devote half that to straightforward storage of 44kHz monaural sound, at 2 bytes per sample, that's about 1.5/3 seconds of sound. Adequate to store one or two siren sounds right on the chip, of CD quality, without resorting to MP3 compression. Since the program to spit out the sound to a CODEC and repeat it would be very small, and 44kHz is gross overkill, that should give you some idea of what's possible in a modern design.

The sounds can be digitally generated and edited offline with a program such as Adobe Audition and then stored in memory, either on the chip or in something like a small SD card.

There are also open-source MP3 decoders such as helix which could be used with a sufficiently powerful microcontroller.

Older designs no doubt used different methods, dedicated chips, etc. right back to the mechanical sirens such as air raid sirens (even [this](https://9gag.com/gag/aw7LzjQ) one powered by a V8 engine):

[image]

[Here](https://www.schukat.com/schukat/schukat_cms_en.nsf/index/FrameView?OpenDocument&art=SAE800G&wg=A3495) is an example of an old-school dedicated chime sound chip.